# ROS audio_common requires gstreamer but apt-get won't install it - CHATBOT

Tags: ros, ros-lunar, audio-common

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to install the Amazon LEX chatbot node from here: https://github.com/aws-robotics/lex-ros1

That node requires the ROS audio_common node from here: https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common

One of the audio_common CMAKE files requires gstreamer-1.0

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GST1.0 gstreamer-1.0 REQUIRED)
```

When I attempt to install gstreamer apt-get is instead referencing different versions of similar programs on my system;

```
b2@b2:~/catkin_ws$ sudo apt-get install gstreamer-1.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libqtgstreamer-1.0-0' for regex 'gstreamer-1.0'
Note, selecting 'gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0' for regex 'gstreamer-1.0'
Note, selecting 'libqt5gstreamer-1.0-0' for regex 'gstreamer-1.0'
libqt5gstreamer-1.0-0 is already the newest version (1.2.0-3).
libqtgstreamer-1.0-0 is already the newest version (1.2.0-3).
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 is already the newest version (1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
```

So I'm tempted to modify the CMAKE file to reference one of these other programs.

QUESTION:
Are any of you familiar enough with the audio_common node to suggest which of the three programs should get referenced, or does it even matter?  I'm willing to experiment but don't want to jackup my system by uninstalling those programs.
Can I force install of gstreamer-1.0?

Environment: 64 bit Ubuntu 16-LTS, ROS LUNAR, Lenovo Thinkpad

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333633/ros-audio_common-requires-gstreamer-but-apt-get-won%27t-install-it---chatbot/) by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1850 on 2019-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All `audio_common` packages appear to state their dependencies correctly in their package manifests.

That leads to two questions:

1. do you need to build the `audio_common` packages from sources? [This](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_lunar_default.html?q=audio) seems to suggest a simple `apt install ros-lunar-audio-common` should work
2. if you need to build from sources: have you ran the obligatory `rosdep install --from-paths /your/catkin_ws/src -i`? Refer to #q252478 for an example workflow.

As a general recommendation: always prefer to use `apt` on Ubuntu. Only build packages from source if you *have* to.

---

Edit:

> Forgive the naivete but how do I know if there is a package I can install through apt?

I believe #q320046 should clear this up.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-09-23**:
Thank you gvdhoom. The apt install got me through that issue.

Forgive the naivete but how do I know if there is a package I can install through apt? I followed your link above to the repositories and found the lex node listed but unable to use apt for that one. It's unclear how I differentiate.

And thank you for the link to the workflow. I've bookmarked that page for reference. The rosdep command is new to me.

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-10-04**:
@gvdhorn, this effort ended up bringing me to this other question that you helped so much with : https://answers.ros.org/question/334178/have-you-typed-make-in-lex_common_msgs/

Well after converting to kinetic and testing the native audio_common I found myself stuck on a known issue with released version of audio_common:  https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/pull/122

So I had to install a patched version of audio_common from source after all.  And I ended back here with the exact same issue but this time on Kinetic.  Your comment about `rosdep install --from-paths /your/catkin_ws/src -i` fixed it up for me though. So your answer actually took care of two issues.  Thank you.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-05**:
No problem.

Glad you got things to work.